# How to refactor code using partial application of quotations?

Tags: factor-lang

How can I use existing combinators to refactor this code so that regex will become argument to be partially applied and resulting quotation will have same identical stack effects as `ls (x -- )`?

```
USING: io.directories locals sequences accessors math 
  prettyprint kernel io.files.info io.directories.hierarchy 
  combinators.short-circuit regexp
  ;
IN: flac

:: job ( step path -- ) 
     path 
     [ [ step call ] each ]
     with-directory-entries
     ; inline
:: lsc ( x c -- ) x c call [ x . ] when ; inline
:: ls ( x -- )
     x 
     [ { 
         [ directory? ] 
         [ name>> directory-tree-files 
           [ ".*[.]flac" <regexp> matches? ] 
           filter length 0 = 
         ]
       } 
       1&&
     ] 
     lsc
     ;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in the original code, it looks like `x` is a `directory-entry`. If `x` is required to stay as a `directory-entry`, then it is impossible to refactor out the regex as an argument, after all there's nowhere to put it!  If `x` is allowed to change to, say a string with the regex embedded, or a collection or object, you can then make the regex part of the single argument -- `x`.

The following solution assumes `x` can be changed into a tuple object with "dir-entry" and "regex" as slots:

```
:: ls ( x -- )
    x
    [ dir-entry>> directory? ].
    [ 
        dir-entry>> name>> directory-tree-files 
        [ [ x regex>> <regexp> matches? ] any? ] [  drop x dir-entry>> ] when .
    ] smart-when* ;
```

Comment: Yes, that task was my motivation to try factor, but question is about refactoring. Code has magic string inside, how to get it out?

Comment: I'm not quite following.  You want to make the regex string an argument to the word?  Yet, you don't want to change the stack effect of the word?  Can you give me a usage example?

Comment: For example, did you want to do something like `"/path/to/dir/.*[.]flac" ls` where the stack effect of `ls` remains the same and you parse out the regex and pass it into the quotation for `filter`?  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Very close. Imagine `ls` is business critical but also legacy mess and your boss hires you to redefine `ls ( x -- )` function as `".*[.]flac" ls-by-regex` so that he can do `".*[.]ogg" ls-by-regex` and pay you ;) How to transform existing code to define `ls-by-regex` and not rewrite from scratch?